# Reliability Function Question

Tags: probability

A device has a failure rate of $1$ failure every $100$ hours ($0.01$ hours/failure or a mean failure time of $100$ hours)? The reliability function is defined as $1-\mathrm{CDF}$:
$$
\mathrm{Rel}(x) = \mathrm{Pr}(X \geq x) = 1-\mathrm{Pr}(X \leq x)
$$

What is the reliability of the device at $t=200$ hours?

Answer (score 2):

According to my understandting this question is related to Poisson distribution. So first of all "failure rate of 1 failure every 100 hours" is the mean failure time. It is not necessarily always the case. The probability mass function of a poisson distribution is given as $$Pr(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}.$$ Here $\lambda$ is the number of events occuring in time interval $T=1$. So this means you have $0.01$. The rest should be easy.